# jQuery Not Setting CSS property

Tags: jquery, html, css, styling

```
var shadeAmount = 161 / $('.header').length;
        $('.header').each(function (i, e) {
            var shade = i * shadeAmount;
            var color = 'rgb(' + shade + ',' + shade + ',' + shade + ')';
            $(this).css({"background-color": color});
        });
```

I cannot get the above code to set the background-color property of each header. If I change the code to this:

```
$(this).css({"background-color": "rgb(1,1,1)"});
```

It works. So what's wrong with the way I'm declaring color?

Comment: Why is there odd number of `"` in `$(this).css({"background-color": "rgb(1,1,1)});`?

Comment: `console.log(color);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
var count = $(".header").length;
if (count) {
    var shadeAmount = parseInt(161 / count, 10);
    $('.header').each(function (i, e) {
        var shade = i * shadeAmount;
        var color = 'rgb(' + shade + ',' + shade + ',' + shade + ')';
        $(this).css({"background-color": color});
    });
}
```

I've just sanitised it by wrapping the calculation of `shadeAmount` in `parseInt`, to ensure you're not passing floats into the rgb value.

I also added a check that there *are* elements with the header class, as your code would fail if you ran it on a page where there were none.

Comment: Ahh,I think you've cracked it! I am parsing floats into the RGB, as it's a division. Thank you very much. I'll try this now.

Comment: Thanks @iambriansreed - I just spotted it as you were changing it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var shadeAmount = 161 / $('.header').length;
$('.header').each(function (i, e) {

    var shade = ++i * shadeAmount;

    var color = 'rgb(' + shade + ',' + shade + ',' + shade + ')';

    console.log(color);

    $(this).css({
        "background-color": color
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mUH2/